# I have a job offer, but only plan to work 4 months until the January 2021 period. What do I tell the employers?

Tags: interviewing, professionalism, communication, job-search

I recently got an offer for a Software Engineering firm to start working in Sep 2020.

I haven't been getting much luck in the job search, and due to COVID many of the companies that I would've liked to work for are not hosting any positions. That being said, I just accepted the first company that gave me an offer, because I just wanted to be safe.

My goal is to work for this company for 4 months, and search for a Jan 2021 position in the mean time. I want to believe that COVID will be at a minimum during the months of Nov and Dec 2020, so positions for Jan 2021 will open.

Here is my problem:

When I start applying in Nov and Dec for a Jan 2021 position, I will only have worked at the firm for 2-3 months.

Employers of the companies I am applying to will likely ask me why I want to leave. What can I say?

Would this response work?

'I chose the first job I could get during the COVID season, and only planned to work here for 4 months until I could find something better'

I feel like its too direct, but it is the truth.

Or do I not need to mention COVID at all?

**Edit:**
Some of you have commented asking why I want to leave this job in the first place. The reason is simply because I have worked with the technologies already before, and as I am still a relative newcomer into the industry, I want to get exposure in other places as well before I find my true passion. I have already had internships where I have worked with these technologies and tools, so I want to try something new.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Should I accept a job that I plan on leaving soon?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/62989/should-i-accept-a-job-that-i-plan-on-leaving-soon)

Comment: If you are uncomfortable telling the truth, it might be useful to examine your own integrity (or lack of it). If the truth of your actions damages your reputation, perhaps you should reconsider what you're about to do. You can sprinkle as much sugar on this as you like. It's not going to turn into candy.

Comment: @JoelEtherton sometimes the truth has to be stated in a another way. For instance, if you left your job because your manager was being an ass to you, well, you have to put that in nice words to your future employer. So yes, although integrity is important, you should sprinkle it

Comment: @KSplitX: Some situations can benefit from such sugary sprinkles. This one isn't one of them.

Comment: Why won't you stay? Have you tried negotiating?

Comment: Re: Your edit. Beware.  Employers don't like serial job-hoppers who keep changing jobs every few months.  Recruiting new employee costs money, and they won't pick you if they think you will only leave a few months later.

Comment: Employers are typically wary of candidates with a history of job-hopping. But one job-hop isn't going to damage you unless you wreck your explanation with "radical honesty". As a newcomer it's not unusual and even expected to have a stint that "didn't work out" for one reason or another. Just don't make a habit of it and you should be OK. You've got to do what's best for your well-being. Employers *always* do that for themselves (and then some), don't feel bad about covering your bases.

Comment: I think many (perhaps not all) employers will be receptive to the argument that you had prior ambitions, but that you've had to take what you can get in the current circumstances until things improved. The more pertinent question may be why you ended up looking for work during the Covid crisis, but if it was itself due to crisis-related redundancy, then I'd expect that to be accepted as a credible explanation.

Answer (score 14):

There's nothing wrong with "I'm unemployed, I'll take whatever is offered just to get money" (to be honest I've done the same thing many times personally).  What is wrong is stating as much to your employer.  That will likely burn your bridge there permanently and make everyone there hate you.  Plus, it's not productive to go in with the mindset of leaving immediately.

Rather than going into your new company with the mindset "win lose or draw, I'm out of here in 5 months", go into your company with the mindset "this is a job that's going to pay me a salary and that's all.  We'll see how it goes, and if things go to crap, I may consider looking for another new job in 5 months, but if I like the job, then I'll stay a while".

The issue shouldn't be "I need a temp job", the issue should be "I need a job, and if it turns out to be a crappy job then I'll look to leave ASAP".  That's basically how all jobs work: you look for a job, you join the company, then if the company sucks you look for a new job, and there's nothing whatsoever wrong with that.

Comment: This answers the question I would ask myself if considering hiring based on the question "How long do you plan to stay here before looking.". It would be better if the OP presents it as "I took a job quickly and it is not giving me X, Y, and Z", where X, Y, and Z are things like technical growth.

Comment: Good advice, but at least in the current version, it doesn't answer OP's question, which is "how do I justify my short employment to the potential employer I will be talking to in 2021".

Comment: @LokiRagnarok Because answering that question presupposes that OP will be talking to another employer in 2021.  That presupposition in itself is a problem which needs to be addressed first, and my answer addresses that, more important and more pressing, concern.

Answer (score 2):

> My goal is to work for this company for 4 months, and search for a Jan
> 2021 position in the mean time. I want to believe that COVID will be
> at a minimum during the months of Nov and Dec 2020, so positions for
> Jan 2021 will open.

Actually your goal is to work for this company until the job situation improves. And by improves that doesn't just mean it becomes easier for you to get a job because companies aren't nervous about hiring new employees when they may still have to make cuts; it also means we know that job stability is returning throughout the economy and therefore all jobs are more stable. overall stability is better because it makes it less likely that jobs cuts come out of the blue.

When will that occur? it depends on the number and severity of the waves. It could be this winter, or it could be a year from now, or even longer.

Once the situation improves there will be many people who wanted to move but couldn't because they didn't want to risk the security they had; they will also be looking for new jobs.

> Employers of the companies I am applying to will likely ask me why I
> want to leave. What can I say?
>
> Would this response work?
>
> 'I chose the first job I could get during the COVID season, and only
> planned to work here for 4 months until I could find something better'

This is how I would answer.

I started working here during the COVID-19 crisis, the job was interesting and stable but not exactly what I was looking for. Now that things are more stable everywhere I am looking for positions that are more appropriate to my skills and interests.

I wouldn't say that the plan was only to stay for 4 months. That just suggests they should be asking how many months will you stay with us. It also looks like you put a number on a duration instead of evaluating the conditions.